Ollama + Local Mistral Nemo: Can't get to understand chat / use tools / talks nonsense despite trying multiple prompt templates
Edit: I can't see where to appeal this ticket being closed so editing it, it is showing as:
"This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers.".
The ticket fulfils all of those requirements? It's a programming issue using ollama, a software tool for running local LLMs, nodejs as the language I'm using to build a client program and AI message templating language where I believe I've done something incorrect. It's not a question about AI development or training, it's a software project to interact with a tested public domain model. I have got the same model to behave correctly in LM Studio so it is definitely a programming issue not that the AI is broken and therefore out of the scope of this question / site.
Is there another reason it has been closed? I've also checked and there isn't another more appropriate stack exchange site for this question.
I need help with this problem, please halp :(
Original Ticket
I've set up a local AI using ollama and am making a local AI assistant.
I've chosen Mistral Nemo because it sits in the max size my computer can handle and is uncensored (although I've heard newer versions have ruined that). I'm making an app using the nodejs ollama library.
I cannot, for the life of me, get this thing to keep up a conversation without b0rking. Let alone do things like use tools which it apparently can. I've managed with other models like llama and such but I run into these issues:

It keeps thinking this is the first message of the conversation (the history is definitely being sent correctly and works with other models)
It decides to continue the conversation without the user, answering it's own questions without the user's input i.e. "User: Tell m about X, Assistant: Something about X, User: That's interesting, tell me more about X, Assistant: Something else about it"
Being obsessed with tools it is provided with, affecting situational context. I.e. if it has a getBookReview test tool, it obsesses that the conversation is taking place in a library or leads conversation to use that tool.
Inserting random python code as a message calling the tool in bizarre ways
Sometimes calling tools correctly / sometimes not.

After a lot of fannying around I realised it needs a defined prompt template and that programs like Lmstudio automatically do this for you. No problem, I look into it, try multiple templates and add it to a custom ModelFile, reload via ollama. Still issues.
Surely I'm doing something obviously wrong here, I imagine other people are using this model and don't have this issue. I can use a template with something like llama 3.1/3.2 and it works perfectly.
Model: hf.co/lmstudio-community/Mistral-Nemo-Instruct-2407-GGUF:Q4_K_M
I load the model in as mytestmodel with ollama create mytestmodel -f model-second.yaml
Most recent ModelFile:
FROM hf.co/lmstudio-community/Mistral-Nemo-Instruct-2407-GGUF:Q4_K_M

TEMPLATE """{{- if .Messages }}
{{- range $index, $_ := .Messages }}
{{- if eq .Role "user" }}
{{- if and (le (len (slice $.Messages $index)) 2) $.Tools }}[AVAILABLE_TOOLS] {{ $.Tools }}[/AVAILABLE_TOOLS]
{{- end }}[INST] {{ if and $.System (eq (len (slice $.Messages $index)) 1) }}{{ $.System }}

{{ end }}{{ .Content }}[/INST]
{{- else if eq .Role "assistant" }}
{{- if .Content }} {{ .Content }}
{{- if not (eq (len (slice $.Messages $index)) 1) }}</s>
{{- end }}
{{- else if .ToolCalls }}[TOOL_CALLS] [
{{- range .ToolCalls }}{"name": "{{ .Function.Name }}", "arguments": {{ .Function.Arguments }}}
{{- end }}]</s>
{{- end }}
{{- else if eq .Role "tool" }}[TOOL_RESULTS] {"content": {{ .Content }}}[/TOOL_RESULTS]
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- else }}[INST] {{ if .System }}{{ .System }}

{{ end }}{{ .Prompt }}[/INST]
{{- end }}
{{ if .Response }} {{ end }}{{ .Response }}
{{- if .Response }}</s>
{{- end }}"""
PARAMETER stop [INST]
PARAMETER stop [/INST]
PARAMETER stop </s>

Code Excerpt
async executeCompletion(
        prompt: string,
        tools: string[],
        messageHistory: AIMessage[],
        convo: AIConvo,
        message: string
    ): Promise<AIMessage[]> {
        


        // Format messages into ollama format
        const messages: Message[] = [
            {role: 'system', content: prompt}
        ];
        for(let historyMessage of messageHistory) {
            messages.push({
                role: historyMessage.role,
                content: historyMessage.content
            })
        }
        messages.push({
            role: 'user',
            content: message
        })

        console.log(messages);


        // Create new ollama client
        const ollama = new Ollama({
            host: 'http://xenomorph:11434'
        });

        // Execute query
        const response = await ollama.chat({
            //model: 'hf.co/lmstudio-community/Mistral-Nemo-Instruct-2407-GGUF:Q4_K_M',
            // model: 'hf.co/lmstudio-community/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct-GGUF:Q8_0',
            model: 'mytestmodel',
            options: {
                num_ctx: 64000,
                num_thread: 16,
                use_mmap: true,
                // temperature: 0.8, // possibly 0.7
                temperature: 0.3,
                top_p: 0.95,
                repeat_penalty: 1.1,
                top_k: 40
            },
            messages
        });

        // TODO execute tools / etc.

        // TODO save messages to database

        // Convert response into normal format
        const responseMessage: AIMessage = {
            id: 1,
            convoId: convo.id,
            stamp: new Date(),
            role: response.message.role,
            content: response.message.content
        };

        // Add both messages to message history
        this.messageHistory.push({
            id: 1,
            convoId: convo.id,
            stamp: new Date(),
            role: 'user',
            content: message
        })
        this.messageHistory.push(responseMessage);

        // Return new messages
        return [
            responseMessage
        ];
    }

I'm aware the code example doesn't use tools, I've used multiple different bits of code to test this and this is just the most recent. I decided not to complicate it by using tools.
